# How to draw a rectangle overlay with fixed aspect ratio that represents a render region?

Tags: opengl

I have a small custom ray tracer that I am integrating in an application. There is a resizable OpenGL window that represents the camera into the scene. I have a perspective matrix that adjusts the overall aspect ratio when the window resizes (basic setup).

Now I would like to draw a transparent rectangle over the window representing the width x height of the render so a user knows exactly what will be rendered. How could this be done? How can I place the rectangle accurately? The user can enter different output resolutions for the ray tracer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, I think that your overlay represents the new "screen" in your perspective frustum.

Redefine then a perspective matrix for the render, in which the overlay 4 corners define the "near" projection plane.

Comment: This kind of works, I can draw an overlay with the correct aspect ratio. However I think the FOV doesn't match the ray tracer focal length so things don't quite match. Anyway will work out the rest. Thanks.